# writing and adding newline after every line in json

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

```
       first =  (str(personaggio["data"]["Character"]["name"]["first"]))
        last =  (str(personaggio["data"]["Character"]["name"]["last"]))
        immagine =  (str(personaggio["data"]["Character"]["image"]["large"]))
        print (f"{first} {last} {id}")
        data = {}
        data["personaggi"] = []
        data["personaggi"].append({
            "id":id,
            "character": [
                {'nome': first,
                'cognome': last,
                'img': immagine}
            ]
            }) 
        id += 1
        with open('idch.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data , outfile)
```

example output:

```
{"personaggi": [{"id": 65, "character": [{"nome": "Pinako", "cognome": "Rockbell", "img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/65.jpg"}]}]}
```

and the output is right. i just need to add new character in newline, like:

```
{"personaggi": [{"id": 65, "character": [{"nome": "Pinako", "cognome": "Rockbell", "img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/65.jpg"}]}]
           [{"id": 66, "character": [{"nome": "x", "y": "x", "img": "y"}]}]
           [{"id": 67, "character": [{"nome": "x", "y": "x", "img": "y"}]}]}
```

im getting the data for every character via a get request, and there isn't a list of all the id's. so i need to loop through every id. the loop is working and everything but i don't know how to print them in the .txt :(

Comment: Why?  Spaces and newlines are totally irrelevant to JSON.  They just get in the way.  You CAN force `json.dump` to make it prettier by passing `indent=2`, but it would be better to let it write things as compactly as possible, and use the excellent `jq` command-line tool if a human being wants to look at the file.

Comment: mh it's not essential to make it pretty, I need it for myself so. and the problem here is that things in"personaggi" is replaced everytime

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with anything here.   And why is `character` a list with one object instead of just being an object?